# Hudson Server Settings for xcode proj

Tags: iphone, ios5, hudson, build-automation

I am using Hudson server for automating build for xcode projects.I am using SVN to check out the code and then do the build.

I just wanted to know if it is possible to configure build settings in hudson so that the local path of the directory can be given so that projects stored locally can be build in Hudson.If anyone has done it before.Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link your files into the project structure which hudson is using. This is described here:

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-BuildsforNonSourceControlProjects